# Using ServiceStack Autoquery With Value Types that don't implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, servicestack, nodatime, autoquery-servicestack

I was trying to use [AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) with a `NodaTime.LocalDate` on a query parameter and I get the following exception when I try to filter using that date field, specifically `>MyDate=2020-01-01` (ordering is unaffected):

```
[MyEndpoint: 5/23/2016 4:19:51 PM]: [REQUEST: {}] System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'NodaTime.LocalDate'. at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider) at ServiceStack.TypedQuery`2.AppendUntypedQueries(SqlExpression`1 q, Dictionary`2 dynamicParams, String defaultTerm, IAutoQueryOptions options, Dictionary`2 aliases) at ServiceStack.TypedQuery`2.CreateQuery(IDbConnection db, IQueryDb dto, Dictionary`2 dynamicParams, IAutoQueryOptions options) at ServiceStack.AutoQuery.CreateQuery[From](IQueryDb`1 dto, Dictionary`2 dynamicParams, IRequest req) at ServiceStack.AutoQueryServiceBase.Exec[From](IQueryDb`1 dto) at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)
```

I tracked it down to [this line of code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/d136f4c5c947de1dd7ab87a3f439ca5f075591b1/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs#L850) that uses `Convert.ChangeType(...)` because `NodaTime.LocalDate` is a `struct` and not an `enum`:

```
var value = strValue == null ? 
      null 
    : isMultiple ? 
      TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString(strValue, Array.CreateInstance(fieldType, 0).GetType())
    : fieldType == typeof(string) ? 
      strValue
    : fieldType.IsValueType && !fieldType.IsEnum ? //This is true for NodaTime.LocalDate
      Convert.ChangeType(strValue, fieldType) :    //NodaTime.LocalDate does not implement IConvertible, so this throws
      TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString(strValue, fieldType);
```

I'm using my [NodaTime ServiceStack](https://github.com/AnthonyCarl/NodaTime.Serialization.ServiceStackText) serialization library so the behavior of `TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString(strValue, fieldType)` is what I actually want in this case.

Workarounds I see are:

- Use `MyDateDateBetween=2020-01-01,9999-12-31` in the query string as that  code path uses the custom serialization I have specified (cumbersome)
- Use `DateTime` instead of `NodaTime.LocalDate` (I want to use `NodaTime.LocalDate`)
- Not use AutoQuery (I want to)
- `NodaTime.LocalDate` implements [`IConvertible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) (not likely)

Is there another way to get auto query filters to work with value types that don't implement `IConvertible`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just added wrapped these lines in a new `ChangeTo()` extension method with an extra check to check for implementing `IConvertible` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/b01143ebea6284f32515d11754e0a2ec96ea4253):

```
public static object ChangeTo(this string strValue, Type type)
{
    if (type.IsValueType && !type.IsEnum
        && type.HasInterface(typeof(IConvertible)))
    {
        try
        {
            return Convert.ChangeType(strValue, type);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tracer.Instance.WriteError(ex);
        }
    }
    return TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString(strValue, type);
}
```

And [changed AutoQuery to use it](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/e6c454f40d538bfadd8161d1a1b1c39dc6c25fd6) so NodaTime's LocalDate should now fall through to the TypeSerializer.

This change is available from v4.0.57 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).